# Trying to divide two sql subqueries but getting 0 instead of decimal

Tags: sql, postgresql

Trying to divide two subqueries but getting 0 instead of decimal.

```
SELECT

(SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    "payments"
WHERE "error" IN ('X', 'Y') AND "created_at" >= '2022-01-25')

/ 

(SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    "payments"

WHERE "created_at" >= '2022-01-25')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to do multiple selects, do *conditional aggregation* instead, and multiply by 1.0 to get decimals:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE "error" IN ('X', 'Y')) * 1.0 / COUNT(*)
FROM "payments"
WHERE "created_at" >= '2022-01-25'
```

Or use `AVG()`:

```
SELECT AVG(case when "error" IN ('X', 'Y') then 1.0 else 0.0 end)
FROM "payments"
WHERE "created_at" >= '2022-01-25'
```